# Haskell Servant client tutorial

Tags: haskell, cabal, servant

I am new to Haskell and Servant and am trying to get an official tutorial up and running. I have been trying to get this tutorial working to have a look at it and have been unable to get it working all day.I hate to post a question like this here but I honestly don't know why the code isn't working as I have made no changes to it. I am wondering has anyone else tried to implement this tutorial and has similar issues.

I have seen posts about some tutorials not working with with current servant versions anymore but this tutorial seems to be the most recent for Servant Client.

This is the tutorial http://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/Client.html

Here is the code

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Client where

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Proxy
import GHC.Generics
import Network.HTTP.Client (newManager, defaultManagerSettings)
import Servant.API
import Servant.Client

data Position = Position
  { x :: Int
  , y :: Int
  } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Position

newtype HelloMessage = HelloMessage { msg :: String }
  deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON HelloMessage

data ClientInfo = ClientInfo
  { clientName :: String
  , clientEmail :: String
  , clientAge :: Int
  , clientInterestedIn :: [String]
  } deriving Generic

instance ToJSON ClientInfo

data Email = Email
  { from :: String
  , to :: String
  , subject :: String
  , body :: String
  } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Email

type API = "position" :> Capture "x" Int :> Capture "y" Int :> Get '[JSON] Position
      :<|> "hello" :> QueryParam "name" String :> Get '[JSON] HelloMessage
      :<|> "marketing" :> ReqBody '[JSON] ClientInfo :> Post '[JSON] Email

position :: Int -> Int -> ClientM Position

hello :: Maybe String -> ClientM HelloMessage

marketing :: ClientInfo -> ClientM Email

api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy

position :<|> hello :<|> marketing = client api

queries :: ClientM (Position, HelloMessage, Email)
queries = do
  pos <- position 10 10 
  message <- hello (Just "servant") 
  em  <- marketing (ClientInfo "Alp" "alp@foo.com" 26 ["haskell", "mathematics"])
  return (pos, message, em)

run :: IO ()
run = do
  manager <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
  res <- runClientM queries (ClientEnv manager (BaseUrl Http "localhost" 8081 ""))
  case res of
    Left err -> putStrLn $ "Error: " ++ show err
    Right (pos, message, em) -> do
      print pos
      print message
      print em
```

Here are the errors I am getting

> ```
> Couldn't match type ‘http-client-0.4.31.2:Network.HTTP.Client.Types.Manager
>                            -> BaseUrl -> ClientM Position’
>                      with ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Except.ExceptT ServantError IO Position’
>       Expected type: Int -> Int -> ClientM Position
>         Actual type: Int
>                      -> Int
>                      -> http-client-0.4.31.2:Network.HTTP.Client.Types.Manager
>                      -> BaseUrl
>                      -> ClientM Position
>     • When checking that the inferred type
>         position :: Int
>                     -> Int
>                     -> http-client-0.4.31.2:Network.HTTP.Client.Types.Manager
>                     -> BaseUrl
>                     -> ClientM Position
>       is as general as its signature
>         position :: Int -> Int -> ClientM Position
>
>
> Variable not in scope:
>       runClientM
>         :: ClientM (Position, HelloMessage, Email)
>            -> t0 -> IO (Either a0 (a1, a2, a3))
>
>
> Data constructor not in scope:
>       ClientEnv
>         :: http-client-0.4.31.2:Network.HTTP.Client.Types.Manager
>            -> BaseUrl -> t0
> ```

Comment: One of your errors is `Variable not in scope: runClientM`. `runClientM`, which is exported by `Servant.Client`, was introduced in Servant 0.9 (cf. [the changelog](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-client-0.9.1.1/changelog) and the Haddock indexes for [*servant-client* 0.8.1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-client-0.8.1/docs/doc-index.html) and [*servant-client* 0.9.1.1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-client-0.9.1.1/docs/doc-index.html)). Are you sure that you are using the latest version of Servant?

Comment: @duplode I have servant-client in my .cabal . Would this use the latest version? I tried to add servant-client >= 0.9 and got the following : Failure when adding dependencies:    
      servant-client: needed (>=0.9), 0.8.1 found (latest applicable is 0.9.1.1)

Comment: Adding `servant-client >= 0.9` to the .cabal file is the right thing to do -- now *cabal-install* demands the version you actually need. The new error message tells you that you currently have 0.8.1, and need to install 0.9.1.1. `cabal install servant` should do the trick. (Note: What I have just said assumes that you are using just *cabal-install*, and not *stack*, to manage your packages and project. If you never heard of *stack*, you can safely ignore this note.)

Comment: @duplode Thanks so much that was the issue!

Comment: @duplode move that to answer :)

Comment: @przemo_li Done. Not sure why I didn't do that back then; thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

The first "not in scope" error here mentions a `ClientM` type which, according to [the *servant-client* changelog](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-client-0.17/changelog), was introduced by the 0.9 version of *servant-client*. Specifying `servant-client >= 0.9` in the .cabal file dependencies will ensure cabal-install won't pull an older version (though note that, as of March 2020, 0.9 itself is quite old already). With cabal-install version 3, no further configuration steps should be necessary, as `cabal build` will automatically install any specified dependencies.